# Will react native be supported by windows?

Tags: react-native

will react native be supported by windows os?Or linux . I don't own a mac so i was wondering if facebook plans to release react native for windows or linux. i don't want to run virtual machine because it's too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows support would be awesome but cannot promise an ETA. We'd be happy to review pull requests that will make the CLI work on Windows.

You could skip the CLI and start with the Sample app from examples, build it with Gradle and start the packager manually using `node node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js`.

Discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2693

Answer (score 1):

I had successfully run the react-native on windows with a few hack.
The gist is here [gist](https://gist.github.com/mqli/e1e6576e9838d885a43a)

Answer (score 0):

This is not official support but I figured out how to get things working on Windows in a way that allows you to use the react-native CLI as documented without having to modify the source code.

The main issue that I encountered was with the hardcoded references to sh in React Native's packager.  I solved this by adding Cygwin's bin directory to my path.  Others have provided solutions for this where they modify the source code to work on Windows but I'd prefer not to go that route in order to ease updating to newer versions of React Native.

The other two catches where having to enable virtualization in my BIOS in order to get HAXM support and having to load the debugger page manually.

I wrote up some notes on the complete process here and intend to keep this up to date with future release of React Native:

http://davidanderson.io/2015/10/18/a-step-by-step-guide-to-react-native-on-windows/